# How to get this structure in mysql script

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have this table in my database see attached images

[image]

Now what i wanted is to count all the or_number and get the total sales_total  with the same sales_date in different sales_branch 
Here is my sample script:

```
    SELECT *,sum(sales_total) as total,group_concat(DISTINCT or_number) as 
    orn FROM `tbl_sales` GROUP by sales_date
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

Which is wrong because it doesn`t count the sales_total and the different sales_branch group into one because the of the sales_date.

Any idea please help.

Comment: `SUM != COUNT` check the syntaxes

Comment: If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: What do you want your output to look like.(add to question)

Comment: Thanks for the efforts @P.Salmon i already got the solution for this post.

Comment: Here is my sql script:
SELECT *,sales_date, sales_branch, COUNT(DISTINCT or_number), SUM(sales_total) AS total_sales
FROM  tbl_sales
GROUP BY sales_date, sales_branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my sql script:

```
SELECT *,sales_date, sales_branch, COUNT(DISTINCT or_number), SUM(sales_total) AS total_sales FROM tbl_sales GROUP BY sales_date, sales_branch
```